# Blank display from integrated graphics Kubuntu 18.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I just installed Kubuntu 18.10 with integrated graphics as the primary display (set from BIOS). All worked fine and I was getting output from the DisplayPort/HDMI from the integrated graphics(from motherboard). Then I installed NVIDIA drivers for my graphics card and rebooted. Now, I get a blank screen from the integrated card outputs and proper display from the additional graphics card.

The issue is that I want the integrated graphic to be my main GPU for display and the additional to be used only for machine learning tasks.

How can I switch back to the integrated GPU as primary display device?

The output from:
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e98
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7b17
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e04 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 12ae
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

From xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   2560x1080     59.98*+  74.99  
   1920x1080     75.00    60.00    59.99    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
USB-C-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

[nvidia-settings output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7DII.png)